# Log flood with Artemis Topic and WildFly

Tags: wildfly, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I have a Spring application deployed on WildFly 12, with a JMS listener:

```
@Component
public class Service {

    @JmsListener(destination = "my-topic")
    public void myTopicListener(Message myTopicMessage) {
    }

}
```

which works okay: whenever I send something to "my-topic" the listener is notified.

The only problem is that when the application starts the log gets flooded with this messages:

```
18:49:00,022 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:01,043 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:02,063 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:03,081 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:04,097 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:05,117 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-5 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:06,136 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:07,151 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:08,164 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:09,180 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-5 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:10,197 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-5 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:11,227 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-5 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:12,245 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:13,275 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-6 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:14,292 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-4 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
18:49:15,308 INFO  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$3@360219ba)) AMQ221052: Deploying topic jms.topic.my-topic
```

What is triggering this log?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0.2 and `spring-boot-starter-artemis`.

Comment: What version of Artemis are you using?  That message is no longer logged since 2.0.0 was released.  If you're still using 1.x I recommend you move to 2.6.0 (just released).

Comment: 1.5.5 which is the one provided by WildFly 12 (current release). I don't know if there is a way to update it to 2.6.0, since AFAIK it has a deep integration with clustering etc.

Comment: Seems like it will be upgraded in WildFly 14: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-10320